# how to decrypt partitions of cipertext - AES, Java

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, aes

I , wrote java method, which encrypts - decrypts data.

```
    String message = "Hello world 123456";

    // Creating Key. Key of size = 128
    byte [] raw ={-49, -44, 51, -114, 58, 79, 83, -38, 107, 64, 67, -108, -52, 109, 85, 77};
    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);

    // Encript
    byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(message.getBytes());
    System.out.println("encripted: " + Arrays.toString(encrypted));
    System.out.println("encripted: "+ asHex(encrypted));

    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
    byte[] decript = cipher.doFinal(encrypted, 0, 32);
```

Everything works well! encrypted bytes size is 32.  That is correct. But can I dencrypt part to part (block to block - for instance, decrypt first block, then second) ? I mean to decript firstly 16 byte and then second 16 byte and etc..

might be something like this.

```
byte[] decript = cipher.doFinal(encrypted, 0, 16);
```

I have such error:

```
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
```

**In the other word, can I decrypt AES cipher text, block to block?**

**Update:**
I have encrypted video file.  It is for about 1 gb. I want to write my video player, which will open my file. If I will decript full video there will be memory problem. So I will give bytes of stream step to step to my player (block to block). Can I use AES for that?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: I have encrypted video file.  It is for about 1 gb. I want to write my video player, which will open my file. If I will decript full video there will be memory problem. So I will give bytes of stream step to step to my player (block to block). Can I use AES for that?

Comment: No, you can't (unless you always start from the beginning of the file).  Read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_encryption_theory

Comment: Should be possible, but probably not with javax.crypto. You probably need to implement the routines yourself, because they are fused in the API. As SLaks notes you would need to start from the beginning to decrypt it in most AES modes. There are also several modes that are helpful for disk encryption and make it decryptable without starting at the beginning.

Comment: @ArtjomB.
Is there anything already implemented? For instance in C++. I want to find anything already written. Or another algorithm, which will help to write my software (video file encription, decription, block to block).

Comment: I have one idea. I can encrypt my video such I way: first I will encrypt 32 bytes. then another 32 byte and etc... So finally I will get video file, which will be encripted block to block... This is possible... is it good idea? does it have anything disadvantages?

Comment: @grep: You just re-invented ECB, which is not secure.

Comment: @SLaks 
Dear my friend. could I  ask you one question again, please? I know ECB, it is very poor. could you tell me which ones are really secures? For instance is CBC really secured?

Comment: CBC has issues if you don't use proper authentication; read about padding oracles.  You need to learn far more about cryptography before you can use crypto primitives correctly to write secure code.

Comment: Use CTR mode to enable decryption starting at any point in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently encrypting using ECB mode encryption. The algorithm string for `Cipher`,  `"AES"`, uses the provider default for mode of encryption and padding. For the SunJCE that translates to `"AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding"` (which actually performs PKCS#7 padding).

ECB encrypts decrypts blocks of 16 bytes. This means that the message is conceptually converted to a concatenation of 16 byte blocks, and each block is then encrypted separately. As each block is encrypted separately, you can also decrypt the blocks separately. That means starting at a block boundary, and then decrypting x times the block size. As you don't want to perform the PKCS#7 unpadding until you reach the last block, you should use an `update` method instead of a `doFinal` method (or you can use `"AES/ECB/NoPadding"`).

If you want to encrypt files you should definitely take a look at `java.nio`, and `Cipher` methods that use `ByteBuffer` as input / output.

---

Note that this is only a direct answer; you should not be using ECB mode encryption. Use CTR with a unique IV (nonce) per key/file combination instead to provide confidentiality of the stream.